# "non-fast-forward updates were rejected" when trying to push remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote project in `projects/my_project`

in my local host i'm in my_project

when trying to push my changes using `git push origin master`

this error appears to me

`To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.`

i need to push to my_project not projects .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have upstream changes. You have two options:

- Execute `git pull origin master`, resolve any conflicts, and then re-push
- Execute `git push -f origin master`. This will totally overwrite the history in your remote repository, so DO NOT do this unless you're absolutely sure.

Comment: when using `git pull origin master` 
I have this error
`* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting`

Comment: If you're ready to commit, then do so. Otherwise, run `git stash` first, and then run `git stash pop` after you've finished resolving merge conflicts

Comment: Don't need to use `git push -f origin master`, I well loss all files in the repo

Comment: Yes, I almost never advise using that command except in special circumstances. Do not do it unless there is absolutely no other choice

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify "master" unless you are trying to push to the remote master branch;

Try:

**git push --set-upstream projects my_project**

This makes the assumption that when you say "projects/my_project" you are referring to
a branch called "my_project" on the remote called "projects".

The --set-upstream set up you current "my_project" branch to track the remote "projects/my_project" branch so you don't need to specify it explicitly every time.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this problem happens because there are changes on the server that you have not pulled to your machine yet. Try doing a pull, fixing any conflicts (if any), and then committing and pushing again.

I would also recomend using something like SourceTree if you are new to git.

Here's the link: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Cheers,